# Cannot print the whole int array

Tags: c, arrays, string, for-loop, atoi

My output : `6 123456 44 0 67 87 0`

What I want is this output: `10 123456 44 0 67 87 0 0 45 55 88`

How come my program didn't print all the integer? Can anyone please help me to check what is wrong with my code? What changes should I make to my code? Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
        char m[100][1000]={"123456","44","","67","87","","","45","55","88"};
        int len;
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        int n;
        int numm[1000];
        n=0;
        len=strlen(m[n++]);
        printf("%d\n",len);
        for (i=0;i<len;i++)
            numm[i]=atoi(m[i]);
        for (j=0;j<len;j++)
            printf("%d\n",numm[j]);
        for (k=1;k<len;k++)
        {
            if (numm[k]>100||numm[k]<0)
            {   
                printf("Error. Marks out of range.\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }   
        return 0;   
}
```

Comment: And I would declare `m` as a global or static variable. It is too big to stay in the local call frame of `main`

Comment: `len=strlen(m[n++]);`  `for (j=0;j<len;j++)`

Comment: Did I edited titles of at least three posts of yours ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20676636/2) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20676129/2)) in the past several days? You don't need to add **Programming in C** in the title as long as you use the tag **c** correctly.

Comment: Try to debug with GDB check https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/ for further information. It will help you to check what is the value of expression at runtime and its also user friendly. Hope this might help you. Thanks

Comment: @YuHao, sorry, I will be more careful on that.

Comment: Even before using a debugger it would help that you take paper and a pen and go through your program step by step. Please do that work by yourself, first. Then if you are at a particular step that you don't understand ask a precise question about that step.

Comment: `len=strlen(m[n++]);` It does not represent the number of elements.

Answer (score 3):

your m array is a 2D array.

```
m[0]="123456" |  m[0][0]='1'   m[0][1]='2'  ...
m[1]="44"     |  m[0][0]='4'   m[0][1]='4'
m[2]=""       |  m[0][0]='\0'
m[3]="67"
```

The

```
int n=0; len=strlen(m[n++]);
```

is equivalent to

```
int n=0; len=strlen(m[0]); n=n+1;
```

so `strlen()` here will return then length of the first strin in the array (`m[0]`) and not the number of element of your `m` array.

Answer (score 1):

```
len=strlen(m[n++]); // m[0]
printf("%d\n",len);
```

Prints length of string "123456" = 6

**[EDIT]**

> How to get length of array

```
    len = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (m && m[i][0] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        len++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",len);
```

**[NOTE]** This works provided you are using `"0"` and not `""` to print `0`

Comment: Okay thanks. How can I get the length of the whole string?

Comment: @user3118123: **Which** "*whole*" string. There are 10.

Comment: @user3118123: does it have constraint that NULL ('\0') is the ending of the array. If yes, count from zero until you encounter '\0'. If not, then you won't know if an element is the last element in the array. So, loop through 100 elements to know the index of the last element.

Comment: updated my ans; have a look

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want that to be output, do it!

Currently, you take the length of the first string, `"123456"`, and abuse it as the length of the array, which is completely unrelated.

The size of the array is computed as `sizeof m / sizeof m[0]`, with `sizeof m` being the total size in bytes and `sizeof m[0]` the size of the first element.

But then you'd print 1000 elements. But you only want to print the declared ones.

As a `char[100][1000]`, this seems quite hard to me; you'd better work with a `char * m[1000]`.

But you could do

```
len = sizeof m / sizeof m[0]; // initial length
while (!m[--len][0]); // decrement len until you find "something".
```

Answer (score 1):

My recomendation is that you should try to debug your code and then line by line see where something its wrong. However most probably your problem is in the index lengths.
In case of every iteration you're still using the same lenght of the string `len=strlen(m[n++]);` which is of course not true for the rest of them.

Try start with first one:

```
len = sizeof m / sizeof m[0];
```

and then look through the table using first index in a loop for example like in the answer of glglgl:

```
while (m[--len][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With a quick look i would say it's because you are using the same  length (len) on both dimension

and your dimensions are differents

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char m[100][1000]={"123456","44","","67","87","","","45","55","88"};
    int len;
    int i,j,k,n;
    int numm[1000];

    for(len = 100 ; len >0; --len)
        if(*m[len-1]) break;
    printf("%d\n",len);
    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
        numm[i]=atoi(m[i]);
    for (j=0;j<len;j++)
        printf("%d\n",numm[j]);
    for (k=1;k<len;k++){
        if (numm[k]>100||numm[k]<0){   
            printf("Error. Marks out of range.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```